# Supporting ios 5 in monotouch applications

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, xamarin.ios

I have an application with monotouch ios (iphone/ipad application). in my project option I target ios 6.

now when I want to download my application with a device that run ios 5 itune not allow.

If I change the target version to the 5, Does my app supports ios 6 and 6.1 yet?

Do I need to change my codes to support both of them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you target iOS 5 in MonoTouch, your app will work on both iOS 5 and iOS 6 devices. In general, nothing special should be done to support both iOS 5 and iOS 6. Keep in mind though, that some APIs are iOS 6 only, such as the deep Facebook integration. So don't worry much about your code, just make sure that you test your app on devices with different iOS versions.